# SFTP connection issue after 10 seconds

Tags: linux, shell, sftp

I'm trying to send files through SFTP by using the below script but after 10 seconds the SFTP connection closed and some files did not send without getting any errors.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
USER=smsu
PASS=XXXXX

expect -c "
spawn sftp -oPort=22 ${USER}@${HOST}
expect \"password: \"
send \"${PASS}\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"lcd /home/suv/msu\r\"
send \"mput *.*\r\"
expect \"sftp>\"
send \"bye\r\"
expect \"#\"
"
```

Comment: First, I would not be coding passwords, use keys instead.

Comment: Honestly why don't you create a key-pair, and then just `scp *.* smsu@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/suv/msu` ...?  Or even use `rsync`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it takes more than 10 seconds to transfer a file, it will timeout, as expect will think it has gone away.

You need something like, from the man page:

```
set timeout 30
```

Comment: It's working fine now, Many thanks.